# JOOQ : getNextException call?

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq, batch-updates

I am using JOOQ's `batch*` methods. I tried with `batchUpdate`, `batchInsert` methods as well.

```
Batch batch = create.batchStore(questions);
int[] counts = batch.execute();
```

Where questions is a list of Generated TableRecords class. I get success while trying to insert data. But I get error while trying to update data.
My query is -

- How to get JDBC error, since I am getting this exception.

  org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [Batch entry 0 insert into ...rest query...] was aborted.  Call **getNextException** to see the cause.

  I don't see `getNextException` method in JOOQ's DataAccessException. I am unable to catch either BatchUpdateException of SqlException in order to get further details about exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jOOQ's `DataAccessException` is an unchecked wrapper for the JDBC `SQLException`. If you want to get a hold of those, you can access the `SQLException` as such:

```
((SQLException) dataAccessException.getCause()).getNextException();
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for this. I have a connecting question. Here I put the changes and got the answer. But is there any way by which I can see these things. I mean a cover for all errors. Sometimes, it becomes hard to put changes on server and see. Thanks again for JOOQ. :-)

Comment: @theGamblerRises: Would you mind asking a complete question here on Stack Overflow for this? I'm not sure yet, if I understand...